# how do I assign multiple IP address when boot

Tags: networking

Currently I directly type the following command to bind static ip for eth0 via normal user.
   `$sudo ifconfig  eth0:1 192.168.20.66`

How do I run this command when boot Ubuntu without typing password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the command in `rc.local` file.

Open gedit with root access `gksu gedit /etc/rc.local`

Before the end line (`exit 0`), put your command without `sudo`

Like

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.20.66
exit 0
```